# How to use \newcommand to define renewed command with two arguments?

Tags: macros, pdftex, color, typewriter, rstudio

I defined a new command as

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

Then, I redefined `\texttt`, so to make it still work, I "stored" the command first and changed the way I define `\code`, so it can still work using stored definition (`%` symbol starts comment in RStudio):

```
\let\oldtexttt\texttt % Store \texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[2][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\ttfamily #2}} % \texttt[<color>]{<stuff>}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\oldtexttt{#1}}
```

Now, I want to change the new command definition, so I can make an use of renewed command `\texttt`, but I don't know how to do this.
I tried using what I found on this page: 
http://noodle.med.yale.edu/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-18.html
and change number of arguments, but I don't know how to accomplish this and make it working.

I did few tries, in the spirit of something similar to:

```
\newcommand{\code}[2][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\texttt {#2}}`
```

or

```
\newcommand{\code}[2][black]{\texttt{\textcolor{#1}{\ttfamily #2}}
```

and few others, but nothing worked.

I would be really grateful for an advice about how to make this correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to directly do `\newcommand{\code}[2][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\texttt{#2}}}` and forget redefining `\texttt`?

Comment: @egreg While you were commenting, I was answering. We crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. Be sure to count the braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\code[2][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\texttt{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\code[red]{Yada yada.} % black if no color specified
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't that clear what you want but after giving `\texttt` an optional argument (it is not generally a good idea to change the syntax of standard latex commands)
then to give `\code` the same optional argument you could use

```
\newcommand{\code}{\texttt}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\code}[2][black]{\texttt[#1]{#2}}
```

either would allow `\code{this}` and `\code[red]{that}`

Comment: Thank you, it works! But you were right that it is not a good idea, as it doesn't really works the way I would want it to work (unless I am doing something wrong) - these new commands, for some reason, don't work after being put within`$` or `$$` display mode. But looks like RobtA's and egreg's proposition works correctly, so I will forfeit what I am doing here and use them instead.

Comment: @Kusavil they should work in math exactly as RobtA's answer, although of course you should never use `$$` in latex anyway.